# My App is not installing from google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have put my app  on testing and then i moved it directly from testing to production after that i got error while installing the app as **can't install** *** . So we have put a new build directly to the production and stopped the tracing in testing. But still we are getting the same error as **can't install ** ***
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNtPf.jpg)

Comment: Do you still have a debug version of your app installed? If yes, uninstall it first.

Comment: Probably you have an older installation of the same app on your device which is signed by another key.